How to Fix VMware Workstation 17.6.1 VMMON VMNET Error on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS for Secure Boot
On a fresh installation of VMware Workstation 17.6.1 I am getting vmmon/vmnet errors.
Download VMware Workstation from Broadcom support:
https://tinyurl.com/vmware176 (shortened because url is too long)
cd Downloads/
chmod u+x VMware-Workstation-Full-17.6.1-24319023.x86_64.bundle
sudo ./VM*
Launch VMware Workstation and secure boot errors
